# Jest throw error SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

Jest config is:

```
module.exports = {
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native)/)'],
  preset: 'react-native',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': require.resolve('react-native/jest/preprocessor.js'),
  },
};
```

In babel config there is `presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],`

In package I have

```
"jest": "^24.9.0",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-native": "^0.64.0",
```

Versions of React and React-native are strict because of youi-tv

If I run jest I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:14
type ErrorHandler = (error: mixed, isFatal: boolean) => void;
```

Also if I use ts-jest with configuration I can get such an error in my *.test.tsx

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Please any advice

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I used more than one string in the "transformIgnorePatterns" on the jest configuration in the package.json.